# uploading multiple files to Nexus using curl commands

Tags: rest, curl, nexus

I'm currently working on getting a script to upload my artifacts to Nexus using CURL.

I can get it to work with one artifact file without any problems using the command:

```
curl -v -F r={repo_id} -F hasPom=true -F e=jar -F file=@pom.xml -F file=@target/project.jar -u un:pwd {repo_url}
```

My project has both a jar containing the binaries and a jar containing the sources though. I would like to deploy both to the same location in my maven repo. I tried this with the curl command by adding a second file,

```
curl -v -F r={repo_id} -F hasPom=true -F e=jar -F file=@pom.xml -F file=@target/project.jar -F file=@target/project-sources.jar -u un:pwd {repo_url}
```

This essentially performs two seperate rest calls for each file, using the same pom. Which doesn't work since my Nexus doesn't allow updating artifacts.

Is there a way to make this work, or can this only work by enabling the updating of artifacts? I would prefer not to enable this for obvious reasons.

Comment: Can you not use the Maven Deploy plugin instead of curl: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/ ?

Comment: We tried using the maven deploy plugin but we're running into a known issue when using maven deploy in combination with Jenkins. About 50% of the time, we run into a fatal error: "missing class X". When we lookup class X in our local maven repo, it IS there. So maven deploy is not working for us.This is why we are looking at alternate solutions. For now, I just disabled uploading the source jars, but we do need a work around for this.

Comment: What about using Aether?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `-Dsources=${YourSourceJar}` to your curl command.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but I wanna add this.

I've run into the same issues/problems during the past days.
To be honest, I couldn't find a solution to upload multiple jars with same pom.xml through curl. I ended up using maven deploy-plugin. Please see my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105003/how-to-upload-jars-with-different-classifiers-and-same-pom-xml-on-nexus-2-from-r/66134509#66134509).

Note: If you want to upload jars with multiple classifiers without the pom.xml - this can be achieved through the rest api.